# How to call a custom control onpaint event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to call OnPaint event in my custom control. I have created a class and inherited control to create custom control and want to call OnPaint or paint event when the object is initialized. But when i create a class paint event is not triggered. Se the below code.

```
internal class CallRectangle : Control
    {

        public CallRectangle()
        {
            this.Paint += CalloutRectangle_Paint;
        }

        void CalloutRectangle_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }       
    }


// Create object to the custom control and call paint event using constructor

 CallRectangle obj = new CallRectangle();
 this.Controls.Add(obj);
```

Any one let me know how to call paint event.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Don't call the event directly, instead use the control's `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` methods. both will force the control to re-draw itself. [some more reading here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/subhagpo/2005/02/22/whats-the-difference-between-control-invalidate-control-update-and-control-refresh/)

Comment: **this.Paint += CalloutRectangle_Paint;** attaches an event to be run onPaint and doesn't trigger the OnPaint event.

Comment: There is no point of calling the OnPaint method in the constructor, since the control is not yet a member of the form, where do you expect to see it?

Comment: Overriding OnPaint() and *not* calling base.OnPaint() will indeed prevent the Paint event from being fired.  Pretty unclear why you overrode it when you have no intention of the method doing anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Calling Invalidate, Update or Refresh **will not work** for you.

Here is a downloadable [Sample from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180794(v=vs.80).aspx) with a Step-By-Step Guide on **how to Inherit Directly from Control** and build the **Draw Events**, since inheriting from a existing control (Button let's say) is quite easy as it already draws it self.

What you'll see in the above example that you'll need to create multiple drawing events based on the complexity of your Control (like a List box that have items that need to be drawn). Sample code from above link:

```
/// <include file='DocumentationComments.xml' path='doc/members/member[@name="M:TwoLineListBox.OnPaint"]/*'/>
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            // draw on memory bitmap
            CreateMemoryBitmap();

            // TODO: Figure out how to avoid doing this on every paint
            // calculate fields required to layout and draw list
            RecalcItems(e.Graphics);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(m_bmp);

            // Draw the background and raise the PaintBackground event
            OnPaintBackground(new ListPaintEventArgs(g));

            // draw list
            if (m_list != null)
                DrawItems(g);

            // Draw the frame around the list
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - m_scrollBarWidth, this.Height - 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), rc);

            // blit memory bitmap to screen
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_bmp, 0, 0);
        }

        // This prevents the base class from doing OnPaintBackground.
        // Since the OnPaint method paints the entire window there's no reason
        // to let this go through. If we do it'll cause flashing.
        /// <include file='DocumentationComments.xml' path='doc/members/member[@name="M:TwoLineListBox.OnPaintBackground"]/*'/>
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        // Called when it is time to draw the background. To take complete control of background
        // drawing override this. To get called after the background is drawn by the base class
        // register for the PaintBackground event.
        /// <include file='DocumentationComments.xml' path='doc/members/member[@name="M:TwoLineListBox.OnPaintBackgroundII"]/*'/>
        protected virtual void OnPaintBackground(ListPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Fill the background with the background colour
            e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
            if (PaintBackground != null)
                PaintBackground(this, e);
        }

        // Called to draw a line item. To take complete control of drawing an item override this method.
        // To let the base class draw the item first and then do your own additional work register for the
        // PaintItem event.
        /// <include file='DocumentationComments.xml' path='doc/members/member[@name="M:TwoLineListBox.OnPaintItem"]/*'/>
        protected virtual void OnPaintItem(ListPaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle();   // Destination for the item image, if any
            Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle();    // Source region of the image to draw
            Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle();   // Destination for the text
            int lineIndent = 0;                     // How far the text is moved in from the left margin before drawing
            Image imageToDraw = null;
            string line1Text;
            string line2Text;

            // On the null case skip everything and just draw the separator line
            if (e.Item == null)
                goto DrawSeparator;


            line1Text = GetStringProperty(e.Item, this.m_line1Property);
            if (line1Text == null)
                line1Text = e.Item.ToString();

            line2Text = GetStringProperty(e.Item, this.m_line2Property);
            if (line2Text == null)
                line2Text = e.Item.ToString();


            // Figure out if we're drawing an image per item from the object, or one for
            // everything
            imageToDraw = GetImageProperty(e.Item, this.m_itemImageProperty);
            if (imageToDraw == null)

                imageToDraw = m_itemImage;

            // Calculate the position of the item image, if we have one, and the line indents
            if (imageToDraw != null)
            {

                srcRect.X = 0;
                srcRect.Y = 0;
                srcRect.Width = imageToDraw.Width;
                srcRect.Height = imageToDraw.Height;

                // int vertPos = (m_itemHeight - m_itemImage.Height) / 2;
                destRect.X = e.ClipRectangle.X + IMAGE_PADDING_X;
                destRect.Y = e.ClipRectangle.Y + IMAGE_PADDING_Y;
                // destRect.Y = (vertPos < 0) ? 0 : vertPos;    // Center the image vertically in the line height. Handle the image being larger than the item height

                // Account for an image that is taller than the item height
                destRect.Height = (imageToDraw.Height > m_itemHeight - IMAGE_PADDING_Y) ? m_itemHeight - (IMAGE_PADDING_Y * 2) : imageToDraw.Height;
                destRect.Width = destRect.Height;
                // Set the text indent based on the image
                lineIndent = IMAGE_PADDING_X + imageToDraw.Width + TEXT_PADDING_X;  // Two pixels for the left indent of the image
            }
            else
            {
                // Set the text indent without using the image
                lineIndent = TEXT_PADDING_X;
            }

            // Calculate the text rectangle
            textRect.X = e.ClipRectangle.X + lineIndent;
            textRect.Width = e.ClipRectangle.Width - TEXT_PADDING_X - textRect.X;   // Allows for padding on the right edge too
            textRect.Y = e.ClipRectangle.Y + 2;
            textRect.Height = this.m_textHeightLine1;

            // From here on we actually draw things. First the selected background, if necessary
            if (e.Selected)
                g.FillRectangle(m_brushSelBack, e.ClipRectangle);

            // Draw the icon, if we have one
            if (imageToDraw != null)
            {
                if (m_useTransparent)

                    g.DrawImage(imageToDraw, destRect, srcRect.Y, srcRect.Y, srcRect.Height, srcRect.Height,
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, m_imageAttributes);
                else
                    g.DrawImage(imageToDraw, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            // Draw the text in a bounding rect to force it to truncate if too long
            g.DrawString(line1Text, m_fontLine1, e.Selected ? m_brushSelText : m_brushText, textRect);

            // Draw the second line
            textRect.Y += m_textHeightLine1 + 3;
            textRect.Height = this.m_textHeightLine2;
            g.DrawString(line2Text, m_fontLine2, e.Selected ? m_brushSelText : m_brushText, textRect);

        DrawSeparator:
            // Draw the separator line
            g.DrawLine(m_penSep, e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y + e.ClipRectangle.Height,
                e.ClipRectangle.X + e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Y + e.ClipRectangle.Height);

            // Let other people know it's time for them to draw
            if (PaintItem != null)
                PaintItem(this, e);
        }


        // Draw all the items.
        private void DrawItems(Graphics g)
        {
            ListPaintEventArgs ListPaintEventArgs = new ListPaintEventArgs(g);

            // Calculate our actual drawing area, accounting for the scroll bar
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - m_scrollBarWidth, this.Height - 1);

            // draw items that are visible
            int curItem = 0;
            for (int i = 0; (i < m_visibleCount); i++)
            {
                curItem = i + m_topItem;
                if (curItem < m_list.Count)
                {
                    // Calculate the drawing area for the item 
                    ListPaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle = new Rectangle(rc.X,
                        rc.Y + (i * m_itemHeight),
                        rc.Width,
                        this.m_itemHeight);

                    // Get the item we'll be drawing with and whether it is selected                    
                    ListPaintEventArgs.Item = m_list[curItem];
                    ListPaintEventArgs.Selected = (m_selItem == curItem);

                    // Draw the item
                    OnPaintItem(ListPaintEventArgs);
                }
            }
        }

        // Recalculates the heights and visible counts for assorted items
        // in the listbox.
        // TODO: Get rid of this method by moving the rest of the items into the assorted
        // properties.
        private void RecalcItems(Graphics g)
        {
            // The text heights for a single line of text is the height of the font.
            m_textHeightLine1 = g.MeasureString("W", this.m_fontLine1).ToSize().Height;
            m_textHeightLine2 = g.MeasureString("W", this.m_fontLine2).ToSize().Height;

            // The height for an individual item is two lines plus some padding
            m_itemHeight = m_textHeightLine1 + m_textHeightLine2 + 5;

            m_visibleCount = this.Height / m_itemHeight;

            // Set the top item to draw to the current scroll position
            m_topItem = m_scrollValue;
        }

        // Creates all the objects we need for drawing
        private void CreateGdiObjects()
        {
            m_brushText = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
            m_brushSelText = new SolidBrush(this.m_selForeColor);
            m_brushSelBack = new SolidBrush(this.m_selBackColor);
            m_penSep = new Pen(this.m_separatorColor);
            m_imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
        }

        // Creates a bitmap in memory to do our drawing. We'll draw on this first
        // and then splat it to the screen.
        private void CreateMemoryBitmap()
        {
            // Only create if don't have one and the size hasn't changed
            if (m_bmp == null || m_bmp.Width != this.Width || m_bmp.Height != this.Height)
            {
                m_bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width - m_scrollBarWidth, this.Height);

                // TODO: Figure out why this is here.
                m_scrollBar.Left = this.Width - m_scrollBarWidth;
                m_scrollBar.Top = 0;
                m_scrollBar.Width = m_scrollBarWidth;
                m_scrollBar.Height = this.Height;
            }
        }
```

I Hope this helps